What happened to AR mode in AFrame?
I'm trying to build a mixed reality experience in A-Frame on Glitch, and I used to see an "AR" button in addition to the "VR" button I currently see. How do I enable AR mode? I'm not using VR for this project.
I'm using the latest 1.6.0 AFrame and I'm expecting to see an AR button but I can't figure out how to configure it.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/favicon.ico" />
    <title>MAPS</title>

    <!-- Import A-Frame Library -->
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Import Hand Tracking Controls -->
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.6.0/aframe-hand-tracking-controls.min.js"></script>

    <!-- The website stylesheet -->
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>

    <a-scene
      xrweb="mode: immersive-ar; requiredFeatures: hit-test; optionalFeatures: dom-overlay; overlayElement: #overlay"
      xr-mode-ui="enabled: true"
      renderer="colorManagement: true; antialias: true; foveationLevel: 1"
      embedded
    >
      <!-- Assets management section -->
      <a-assets>
        <img
          id="yosemite"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.me/4fc60967-2f19-4e8f-b905-44c0d1c89db7/8798000.png?v=1728421365754"
        />
      </a-assets>

      <!-- Camera setup with hand tracking controls -->
      <a-camera
        position="0 1.6 0"
        look-controls="enabled: true; pointerLockEnabled: true"
        wasd-controls="acceleration: 50"
      ></a-camera>

      <!-- Left and Right Hand Tracking -->
      <a-entity
        id="leftHand"
        hand-tracking-controls="hand: left; modelColor: #ffffff; modelOpacity: 0.8; modelStyle: mesh"
        hand-tracking-grab-controls="hand: left; hoverEnabled: true; hoverColor: #538df1"
      ></a-entity>
      <a-entity
        id="rightHand"
        hand-tracking-controls="hand: right; modelColor: #ffffff; modelOpacity: 0.8; modelStyle: mesh"
        hand-tracking-grab-controls="hand: right; hoverEnabled: true; hoverColor: #538df1"
      ></a-entity>

      <!-- Lights to illuminate objects (adjust as needed, but no global light to interfere with AR passthrough) -->
      <a-light type="ambient" color="#ffffff" intensity="0.7"></a-light>
      <a-light
        type="directional"
        position="1 3 1"
        color="#ffffff"
        intensity="0.6"
      ></a-light>

      <!-- Grabbable Plane -->
      <a-plane
        position="0 2 -2"
        rotation="0 0 0"
        width="1.5"
        height="1.5"
        material="src: #yosemite; transparent: true; alphaTest: 0.5"
        grabbable
      ></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>



Got it to work by fiddling with the scene setup:
    <a-scene
  xrweb="mode: immersive-ar; requiredFeatures: hit-test; optionalFeatures: dom-overlay; overlayElement: #overlay"
  xr-mode-ui="enabled: true; enterAREnabled: true; XRMode: ar;"
  renderer="colorManagement: true; antialias: true; foveationLevel: 1"
  embedded
>


As of v1.6.0, here are the simple controls for the standard AR and VR buttons...



Property
Description
Values
Default




enabled
Whether or not to display UI related to entering VR.
true, false
true


XRMode
If the AR button, VR button, or both buttons will be displayed.
ar, vr, xr
vr



Note: Use 'xr' if you want to support both modes.
Use this with <a-scene> like so...
<a-scene xr-mode-ui="enabled: true; XRMode: xr;">


Prior to version 1.5.0, the default mode was 'xr'.

This related answer has a link to the latest documentation: How do I hide the VR Mode / Goggles icon for A-Frame?
